# Adding a "Hamburger" Menu to IOS application

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, menu, hamburger-menu

I am trying to create a hamburger menu that when you click the "hamburger" (three horizontal lines) button, the menu will slide out. I am following the tutorial found [here](https://blckbirds.com/post/side-menu-hamburger-menu-in-swiftui/), but the only thing that isn't working is the lines for the Hamburger image is not showing up on my application. Everything else works, but for some reason this is the one thing that is not working.

Here is my code for the ContentView, where it hosts the problem code

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showMenu = false
    var body: some View {
        let drag = DragGesture()
                   .onEnded {
                       if $0.translation.width < -100 {
                           withAnimation {
                               self.showMenu = false
                           }
                       }
                   }
               
               return NavigationView {
                   GeometryReader { geometry in
                       ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                           MainView(showMenu: self.$showMenu)
                               .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                               .offset(x: self.showMenu ? geometry.size.width/2 : 0)
                               .disabled(self.showMenu ? true : false)
                           if self.showMenu {
                               MenuView()
                                   .frame(width: geometry.size.width/2)
                                   .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                           }
                       }
                           .gesture(drag)
                   }
                       .navigationBarTitle("Side Menu", displayMode: .inline) // this works 
     //somewhere below here is the problem  
                 .navigationBarItems(leading: ( 
                           Button(action: {
                               withAnimation {
                                   self.showMenu.toggle()
                               }
                           }) {
                               Image(systemName: "three_horizontal_lines")
                                   .imageScale(.large)
                           }
                       ))
               }
           }
       }
```

Here is the MainView:

```swift
struct MainView: View{
    @Binding var showMenu: Bool
    var body: some View{
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation{
            self.showMenu = true
            }
        }){
            Text("Show Menu")
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, this is the MenuView:

```swift
struct MenuView: View{
    var body: some View{
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "person")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                Text("Profile")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
                .padding(.top, 100)
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "envelope")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                Text("Messages")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
                .padding(.top, 30)
            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "gear")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .imageScale(.large)
                Text("Settings")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .font(.headline)
            }
                .padding(.top, 30)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .background(Color(red: 32/255, green: 32/255, blue: 32/255))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}
```

I have checked for any misspellings and even copied and pasted the code from the original tutorial, but it seems nothing allows me to see the burger image like is shown on the tutorial. Any thoughts on what else I could try?

Comment: could you try: `Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal")` or `Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")` instead of : `Image(systemName: "three_horizontal_lines")`

Comment: It should be `Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")` for a hamburger style menu. `"line.3.horizontal"` doesn't exist in SF Symbols

Comment: @Andrew Thank you! I didn't recognize that they were using SF symbols!

Comment: @Andrew, "line.3.horizontal" does exist in my SF Symbols, SF 3.0 . If you want your app to work in the future use  "line.3.horizontal" because "line.horizontal.3" does not exist. in SF 3.0

Comment: @workingdog that will be why I can only see `line.horizontal.3` in mine as I have SF 2.1